# Access to elementRef in click event in Angular

Tags: javascript, angular

I defined string list in Component and it's rendering in view like this:

```
<span  class="one" (click)='do($event, index, item)' 
*ngFor="let item of result;let index = index"  >{{item}} </span>
```

After each item clicked I want to add div element after that item:

```
clickedSpan.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', '<div >Hi!</div>');
```

How can I access to **elementRef** in `do` function? Or Are there other solutions to manipulate rendered spans which rendered by ngFor?

Comment: `<span #el (click)="do(el)">` -> https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/template-syntax.html#!#ref-vars

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I template you can create one variable like "#addDivElement" in span tag

You can access these variable in component by using

```
@ViewChild('addDivElement') and you can do render the HTML element as you want 

import { Component, ViewChild, ElementRef, Renderer} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    templateUrl: '/app/angular/app.angular.core.html'
})
export class AppComponent {

    @ViewChild('addDivElement')
    public addElement: ElementRef;

    public constructor(private rendere: Renderer) {

    }

    public arrayData = ["Item1", "Item2", "Item3"];

    public doSomething(event, index, item) {
        this.addElement.nativeElement.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', '<div class="two">two</div>');

    }
}
```

Comment: how to do this for multiple spans? for example spans generated by NgFor. thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
      do(event, index, item) {
          this.result.splice(index, 0, 'Hi!');
      }
```